# ajaxComplete not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why this isn't working, i've looked at many questions here at stackoverflow but can't find anything wrong with my code.

I have a #loading div that i want to remove when the ajax call is complete. This is my code and ajaxComplete is never called.

What am i doing wrong?

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        console.log("ajax start");
        $("#loading").show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        console.log("ajax complete");
        $("#loading").remove();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/listAllDevices")' + '?limit=' + 300 + '&offset=' + 10,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: 'false',
            global: true,
            success: function (listAllDevicesResponse) {
                console.log("ajax done");
                console.log(listAllDevicesResponse);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You might want to hide the loading tag on ajax complete instead of remove it. Is your ajaxStart function getting called? Have you tried some Console.log to see if the method is getting called but not doing what you expect?

Comment: So you didn't see "ajax done" in console? You should add [error handler](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and inspect what is going wrong.

Comment: Ajax done is fired, i also addes console.logs to Start and Complete, but they never go off.

Comment: @Shriike you can see my logs in the code now, only ajax done and my objects get printed in the console.

Comment: Have you tried on $(document).on("ajaxComplete", (){
     $("#loading").remove();
  })

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson the code works "as is" in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmp4nnt7/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no ajaxComplete event handler for the $.ajax object, instead use done or always. There is also the complete event handler but it was deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    console.log("ajax start");
    $("#loading").show();
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/listAllDevices")' + '?limit=' + 300 + '&offset=' + 10,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: 'false',
        global: true,
        success: function (listAllDevicesResponse) {
            console.log("ajax done");
            console.log(listAllDevicesResponse);
        },
        always: function() {
          console.log("ajax complete");
          $("#loading").remove();            
        }
    });

});
```

You can read more about the jQuery $.ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I don't see anything about this being deprecated in the jQuery documentation. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: I think this is right, I ran into this a while ago. success, done, and error.

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

This text can be found on the link I provided in my answer.

Comment: I disagree with your answer, he can indeed use AjaxComplete, ref: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why your complete function is not called, however I would recommend using stop. ajaxComplete is called everytime an INDIVIDUAL ajax request finished. ajaxStop is called when ALL requests have finished. Like so:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    console.log("ajax start");
    $("#loading").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    console.log("ajax complete");
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

References:

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/